# how to call a function from a different class in c++?

Tags: c++, function, class, variables, call

i've got two classes, Apple and Banana. i want to change the value of iTestA (class Apple) in the class Banana with the function callItestA.
i tried using pointers but it didn't seem to work (the value didn't change)...

here's my Banana.cpp

```
#include "Banana.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//Konstruktor
Banana::Banana()
{
    cout << "i'm a banana" << endl;
}

//Destruktor
Banana::~Banana()
{
}

//write test
void Banana::writeBanana(){
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("banana.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
    myfile << "more bananas\n";
    myfile.close();
}

void Banana::callIsetA(Apple a){
    //set iTestA in class Apple to 2
    a.setItestA(2);
}
```

and Apple.cpp

```
#include "Apple.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int itestA = 0;

//Konstruktor
Apple::Apple()
{
    cout << "i'm an apple" << endl;
}

//Destruktor
Apple::~Apple()
{
}

//write test
void Apple::writeApple()
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("apple.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
    myfile << itestA;
    //myfile << "more apples\n";
    myfile.close();
}

void Apple::setItestA(int i)
{
    itestA = i;
}
```

i hope you can help me!

EDIT:
My Banana.h

```
#ifndef BANANA_H
#define BANANA_H

class Apple;

class Banana
{
public:
    Banana();
    ~Banana();
    void writeBanana();
    void callIsetA(Apple);
};

#endif
```

and Apple.h

```
#ifndef APPLE_H
#define APPLE_H

class Banana;

class Apple
{
public:
    Apple();
    ~Apple();
    void writeApple();
    void setItestA(int i);
private:
    int itestA;
};

#endif
```

Comment: you are passing the apple by value. The apple inside that function is a different apple than the one you pass as parameter (it is a copy). Use pass-by-reference if you want to change the apple inside the function. ie. use `void Banana::callIsetA(Apple& a){ a.setItestA(2);}`

Comment: I would really like to see your headers as it is kind of difficult to go by only the implementation. Also tobi is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you pass the copy of Apple instance into the function. So this code changes the value of copied object.

```
void Banana::callIsetA(Apple a){ //here is the definition of argument copy, next code will change it but not the object that was passed in to the function as initial argument
    //set iTestA in class Apple to 2
    a.setItestA(2); 
}
```

To change the value of the original object you need to pass its reference. This may look like this:

```
void Banana::callIsetA(Apple& a){
    //set iTestA in class Apple to 2
    a.setItestA(2);
}
```

Comment: if i use this solution i receive the error message 
'incomplete type is not allowed' for a.setItestA(2);

Comment: Neither `Banana.h` nor `Banana.cpp` are including `Apple.h` to define what `Apple` actually looks like, that is why `Apple` is flagged as an incomplete type in `Banana::callIsetA()`. `Banana.h` has a forward declaration of `Apple`, but `Banana` cannot declare `callIsetA(Apple a)` with just a forward declaration, it needs to be `callIsetA(Apple &a)` instead. Then `Banana.cpp` needs to include `Apple.h` so `callIsetA()` knows about `Apple::setItestA()` and how to access it on an `Apple` object.

Answer (score 0):

there are some ways to do that. one way use extern variables(Global):

in class A:

```
int a = 2;
```

in class B:

```
extern int a;
```

now variable a is in both classes and you can  change it in both classes.

what is extern?
 The extern keyword declares a variable or function and specifies that it has external linkage (its name is visible from files other than the one in which it's defined).   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have some confusion going on here!

In class Banana, this code simply takes an integer parameter and sets itestA (which is a global variable not even a member of either Banana or Apple) to that value:

```
void Apple::setItestA(int i){
itestA = i;
}
```

And what are you trying to do in `callIsetA`? I can't guess

I would look hard on the code again, and maybe read this tutorial on [passing by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/).

Good luck!